# HibernateDAOSupport Get method

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working on a existing project which uses Hibernate and Spring. I see a following code which uses HibernateDAOSupport class,

```
Employee emp = getHibernateTemplate().get(Emplyee.class, 1001)
```

After the above line we set some property like `emp.setAge(25);` and at the end we don't call any Save or SaveOrUpdate method. But it's saving the data to DB. How is it possible ?

If it can Save then what is the difference between `getHibernateTemplate().get()` and `getHibernateTemplate().save`/`SaveOrUpdate` methods ?

Comment: Have you searched through the source for `Save` / `SaveOrUpdate` to be sure they're not called?

Comment: Probably you call your DAO from a Service which is annotated with @Transactional. So when the service method ends the transaction ends and changed entities are flushed to db because they are managed by the JPA EntityManager.

Comment: @xxbbcc: Yes. No Save / SaveOrUpdate method are called.

Comment: @Mike Argyriou: I see transactional annotation in bean class. Will that cause this persistence ?

Comment: Yes @Transactional is responsible for the container starting and ending the transaction (and flushing the changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour of Hibernate and it is because the `Employee` entity is loaded into the `PersistenceContext` and therefore enters the 'persistent' entity lifecycle state.

When you commit the transaction, Hibernate will check any 'persistent' entities within the `PersistenceContext` to see if they are "dirty". Dirty means that any values of the entity have changed. Your call to `emp.setAge(25)` means that Hibernate understands that data within the entity has changed (it is dirty), and it should therefore make the changes persistent when the transaction commits.

It is worth reading and understanding how Hibernate manages entity states as it can be a little confusing to start with. The documentation is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview).

Comment: I agree. Then there is no need for Save / SaveOrUpdate method ?

Comment: They do have slightly different semantics. Save will only work to make new transient instances persistent. It will not update existing instances. SaveOrUpdate will either make a new transient instance persistent, or update an already persistent instance.